# Recode every i to i+1 indexed item in a vector based on value of i

Tags: r, indexing, plyr

I'm trying to devise an approach to recoding items in a vector based on whether or not they occur AFTER a certain value in that vector.  I've got an intact dataset (a time series grouped by subject) that contains a column indicating the month of initial exposure by subject (this column has NA for lack of exposure and "G" for month exposure occured).  Once the subject has been "exposed", I need the vector for that subject to indicate that he/she has been exposed until the end of the observation period for that subject.  Here's a stripped down example and a solution that works some, but not in every case I need it to:

```
x2 <- c("G", NA, NA, NA, NA)
solution <- c(rep(1, length(x2)- length(rep("G", (length(x2)+1 )- which(x2=="G")))), rep("G", (length(x2)+1 )- which(x2=="G")))
```

In this case the solution looks like this:

```
> solution
[1] "G" "G" "G" "G" "G"
```

That said, the solution breaks when confronted with a vector that does not include any "G"s

```
x2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
solution <- c(rep(1, length(x2)- length(rep("G", (length(x2)+1 )- which(x2=="G")))), rep("G", (length(x2)+1 )- which(x2=="G")))

Error in rep("G", (length(x2) + 1) - which(x2 == "G")) : 
  invalid 'times' argument
```

So, at the end of the day, the solution vector needs to:
1) be of the same length as the original vector (x2 in this case) AND
2) contain the value "G" in every position AFTER the initial "G" in the original vector

One more thing, I need the solution to be in some form that I can pass to plyr over a grouping factor (as I need to recode many vectors grouped by factor over a large dataset).

Thank you all very much in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 2):

This works too:

```
x2 <- c(NA,"G", NA, NA, NA, NA)
ifelse(seq_along(x2)>=match('G',x2),'G',x2)
```

This question has been asked before... I think, I am trying to dig up the old question.

Comment: Beauty! I'll most definately read up on ?seq_along! Looks to be pretty handy.  Many, many THANKS nograpes!

Comment: `seq_along` just creates a vector from 1 to the `length(x)`. The key to the solution really is `match`. Try running each part on its own to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
repG <- function(x, start) { patt <- paste0("^",start,"$")
  if( length(grep(patt, x))>0 ){ x[ grep(patt, x)[1]:length(x)] <- start
         return(x) } }
 grep("^G$", tvec)
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: DWin, your solution also breaks when confronted with a vector of NAs.

Comment: Nice. DWin, looks like you have built into your function a way to customize the start character.  Can't wait to give it a try!  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Glad you found it useful. I think you should give @nograpes the check. His approach is more straightforward and avoids the problem with length-0 vectors. You might want to remember for future coding that `match` will give one number per element in "x", while `grep` will return as many numbers as there are "hits".